# Implementing Knockout.js destructive foreach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

Here's the html with the data-bind elements:

```
div data-bind="foreach: clientRequests" id="test2">
           <div class="list-group" >
               <a href="#" class="list-group-item active"><b data-bind="text: client"></b></a>
               <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><b>Priority: </b><b data-bind="text: client_priority"></b></a> 
               <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><b>Title: </b><b data-bind="text: title"></b></a>
               <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><b>Description: </b><b data-bind="text: description"></b></a> 
               <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><b>Product Area: </b><b data-bind="text: product_area"></b></a>
               <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><b>Target Date: </b><b data-bind="text: target_date"></b></a>
               <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><b>Ticket URL: </b><b data-bind="text: ticket_url"></b></a>
           </div>
        </div>
```

This is how I'm passing an array called `requestsArray` to the `foreach` loop:

```
ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById('test2'));

        ko.applyBindings({
            clientRequests: requestsArray
        }, document.getElementById('test2'));
```

With various AJAX calls, different requestArrays are returned. For example, after initial page load an AJAX call is made that receives one instance of the requestArray which may have 10 items. The foreach loop seems to behave as expected, and all 10 items in the array are populated on the page. Then, a second AJAX call is made, but this time the array maybe only has 5 items. What happens is that each item is repeated twice, and a total of 10 items appears on the page.

The problem seems to be that, even though `ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById('test2'))` is called before:

```
ko.applyBindings({
                clientRequests: requestsArray
            }, document.getElementById('test2'))
```

with each new array, the number of HTML elements created by each `foreach` iteration keeps increasing with each new array. With Vue.js, each time you pass a new array to the data-binding and for loop, it's destructive in nature and doesn't preserve anything from the previous iteration over the array.

Obviously using `ko.cleanNode` doesn't work here in this scenario, and I know [in the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) there is an example that does do what I think is the correct procedure, but only one html element at a time via a button and `self.array.remove(this)`, and I'm not quite sure how to adapt it to do a total clearing-out of all html elements created from an array `foreach` iteration.

Comment: why don't you empty your array in your model every time you call Ajax ?1

Comment: @Matt.kaaj I am doing that, will update my code in the post. It doesn't help with what's going on with the Knockout.js binding. Updating the array itself isn't the issue, it's the accruing of the html elements created with each foreach iteration through each new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you'd have to re-apply bindings manually. The whole point of a view model with an observable array is that knockout takes care of the data updates for you... Usually, when you're using `cleanNode`, there's an easier way to do things.

Have you tried something like this?

```js
// Apply bindings _once_, viewmodel instance does not change
// in between requests
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());


function ViewModel() {
  // Because the array is observable, knockout will
  // monitor for changes and update the UI
  this.requests = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  // The view model has the request method
  // the .done callback writes the results to the observable
  // requests array
  this.doRequest = function() {
    mockupAjaxGetter().done(this.requests);
  }.bind(this);
  
  // Do an initial request
  this.doRequest();
};



// Mockup code, just to produce some random numbers on a timeout
function mockupAjaxGetter() {
  var randomResults = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.random() * 20; i += 1) {
     randomResults.push(Math.random()); 
  }
  var cb;
  var applyCb = function() {
    if (cb) cb(randomResults); 
  }
  
  setTimeout(applyCb, 500);
  
  return {
    done: function(fn) { cb = fn; }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: requests">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
<button data-bind="click: doRequest">New request</button>
```